# How to create working buttons on discord.js v14?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make normal buttons for several days now, but without success. I don't know what to do anymore.

Here is my previous code:

```
const { ComponentType, ButtonBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonStyle, EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {

  cooldown: 60,

    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()

        .setName('help')

        .setDescription('Здесь будет помощь для навигации по мне.'),

    async execute(interaction, client) {

    const asyli = new ButtonBuilder()

            .setCustomId('asyli')

            .setLabel('Asyli')

            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);

        const back = new ButtonBuilder()

            .setCustomId('back')

            .setLabel('Назад')

      .setEmoji('1134375940248588328')

            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);   

    const butmenu = new ActionRowBuilder()

            .addComponents(asyli);

    const menu = new EmbedBuilder()

       .setColor(0xB22222)

     .setTitle(`Помощь для ${interaction.user.username}`)

       .setDescription('Я собрала здесь все важные команды обо мне, глянешь?')

    .setThumbnail('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1134131365462409356/1134131416431599646/image.png')

     .setImage("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1134125066662187163/1134154532646039663/image.png")

     .addFields({ name: 'Характеристики', value: 'Язык: JavaScript <:emoji_3:1134375541009551430> \nБибилиотека: discord.js <:emoji_2:1134375519085928528> \nВерсия: 0.1 beta <:emoji_4:1134376649010446337> ', inline: true })   

           .addFields({ name: 'Прочие', value: `Создатель: <@1013426560121978893> | [Профиль](https://discordapp.com/users/1013426560121978893/)\nКоличество серверов: ${interaction.client.guilds.cache.size}\nМоя задержка: ${interaction.client.ws.ping}мс`, inline: true }) 

     .setFooter({ text: ' 2023'});

        const assyli = new EmbedBuilder()

       .setColor(0x0050ff)

     .setTitle(`Asyli - бот для вас`)

       .setDescription('Asyli - Много функциональный бот который имеет всё что нужно!')

    .setThumbnail('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1134125066662187163/1134486479335338174/cc22845f9f6e70403d6ca815b6d96917.png')

     .addFields({ name: 'Добавить Asyli', value: '[клик](https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?scope=bot+applications.commands&client_id=1014449986156638338&permissions=8)', inline: true })   

           .addFields({ name: 'Сервер Asyli', value: `[клик](https://discord.gg/st5uPyADyC)`, inline: true }) 

     .setFooter({ text: 'Asyli ♥️'});

    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [menu], components: [butmenu]});

    const collector = await interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector()

    collector.on('collect', async i => {

      if (i.customId === `asyli`) {

                if (i.user.id !== interaction.user.id) {

                    return i.reply({ content: `Only ${interaction.user.tag} can use there button`, ephemeral: true})

                }

                interaction.editReply({embeds: [assyli] });

            }

    })

       },

    };
```

The problem in the code is that it starts to conflict after sending two identical commands and pressing the button

Fix my code or show normal and working buttons.